# Suggestions for opensource jquery combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, widget

I am about to start a new project of my own that will extensively use combo boxes. Thus I am looking for a large set of configuration options and pretty extensive functionality. At the same time it must be an opensource solution that is easy to work with and is relatively well documented, but most importantly I need something that is easy to develop with :)
I know it is a very broad question but I hope to get some decent suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about jquery ui combobox. It also have an autocomplete in it.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: It looks nice. I will take a look into the documentation and feature list. If you have other suggestions please share :)